# Setting Wordpress base URL when moving to virtual domain for localhost?

Tags: php, wordpress, wamp, wampserver

I had a project on localhost, now in wamp I setted virtual domain. Now the local project opens fine on domain address but resource files on pages are not loading. In source code of pages css and js files are still linked with 'localhost' hence are not found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its very simple

Edit wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Edit functions.php

and add the line

```
<?php
update_option('siteurl','http://example.com');
update_option('home','http://example.com');
?>
```

Take care of permalinks .htacess file & database resources links

You can check [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)

Comment: Great, hope you got your answer.

Comment: Better you add it in functions.php also It will help you in future

Comment: It works partially to me, using your sample. I have a logo from my page showing in the header page. I use <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" to get the logo piccture. The problem is that  get_theme_mod returns the local development site path. I need get_theme_mod function returning the site url. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

In your `wp-config.php`, add these two lines.

```
define('WP_HOME','sitename/');
define('WP_SITEURL','sitename/');
```

Also, you need to edit the SQL file to change the resource locations.

I wrote this tutorial which shows you how to do that.

It's [here](http://www.mrgeek.me/technology/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-migrate-or-move-wordpress-from-localhost-to-a-web-server/), on my blog.

Comment: Did it work, if it did, don't forget to +1 and mark as solve.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain your ability to upgrade WordPress in one click, never edit the WordPress core code.  Instead, you can use [their recommended (clean "drop-in") solution](http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress):

Create a new file at `/wp-content/db.php` with this content:

```
<?php

/**
 * @see http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress
 */
add_filter('pre_option_home', 'test_localhosts');
add_filter('pre_option_siteurl', 'test_localhosts');

function test_localhosts()
{
    if (isDevEnvironment($_SERVER)) {
        return "http://mysite.local/blog"; //Specify your local dev URL here.
    } else {
        return false; // act as normal; will pull main site info from db
    }
}

/**
 * Logic to determine the environment (dev or prod)
 * @return bool 
 */
function isDevEnvironment($serverArray)
{    
    return strpos($serverArray['SERVER_NAME'], 'mysite.local') !== false;//Edit this function such that it returns a boolean based on your specific URL naming convention.
}
```

Now, your local development environment will use its own base URL, and then when you deploy a copy of your codebase to a production environment, it will use its production base URL automatically.

Comment: suppose i am on www.test.com/xyz ok and i want move it on www.myown.com so how will the code structure without editing and firing a multiple query i just want make automated when shifting one domain to another

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to change your local links to live links.
For that, Update your database with some query.

:: Queries to change URL for WP Website

```
UPDATE pvgc_options
SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://pleasantviewgarden.hideoutdev.co.uk/',
                           'http://pleasantviewgardencentre.com/')
WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE pvgc_postmeta
SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, "http://whynickoli.com/", "http://localhost/onestopproperty/");

UPDATE pvgc_posts
SET guid = REPLACE(guid, "http://whynickoli.com/", "http://sparsh-technologies.co.in/megha/onestopproperty/");

UPDATE pvgc_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, "http://whynickoli.com/",
                           "http://sparsh-technologies.co.in/megha/onestopproperty/");
```

Here you should use your domain.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also do an .sql dump of your database, and use find/replace. Then import the dump in your database.

Comment: Both are equal. Use whatever easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the wp-config.php settings for a new domain:

```
define('WP_HOME','siteurl');
define('WP_SITEURL','siteurl');
```

Search and replace on the database with [InterconnectIT Search and Replace Tool](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). With that tool it's easy to search through the entire database for all occurrences of old domain, and replace that with the name of new domain